# How to close kendo window through jquery onsucess on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have this attachments column

```
 columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Attachments").Click("showAttachments")).Width(100).Title("Attachments");
```

and my kendowindow

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Attachments")
.Title("Upload Attachments")
.Visible(false)
.Modal(true)
.Draggable(true)
.Width(350)
```

)

And

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="attachment">
 <a data-role="button" onclick="myFunction();" class='k-button'>Upload</a>
```

button onclick

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    var ln = document.getElementById("NumInput").value;
    var fil = document.getElementById("files");
    var filepath = fil.value;            
    var assetid = document.getElementById("hdassetid").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Asset/SaveAssetAttachments',
        data: { filename: ln, filepath: filepath, assetid: assetid },
        success: function (data) {
             $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
         },
        })
    };
```

and here is code for opening window when show Attacments function called

```
function showAttachments(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var attachmentTemplate = kendo.template($("#attachment").html());
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#Attachments").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(attachmentTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
 <scrip/>
```

Here i want to close kendowindow onupload sucess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got through this .kendo window will close and alert message will display

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/Asset/SaveImages',
         data: { imagepath: imagepath, assetid: assetid },
         error: function () {
             $("#Images").data("kendoWindow").close();
             alert('Images uploaded Sucessfully');
         }
     })
```